# Removing rel canonical added by Yoast SEO plugin from filter pages

Tags: filter, canonical-link, yoast

I do Use filter plugin that generate get parameters like this
https://example.com/product-category/mobile-phone/?product_brand=sony

and yoast plugin removes all the parameters after the "?" by "rel canonical" tag and 
it makes it like this:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://example.com/product-category/mobile-phone/" />
```

1- i need a function to disable canonical from "?" parameters.

yoast already introduced a lot of "[remove functions](https://gist.github.com/amboutwe/2aa7dcc9a38986e11fac68c7306cc091)" but not like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code:

```php
function yoast_seo_canonical_change_product_category( $canonical ) { 

    if ( is_product_category() ) {      
        $canonical = false;
    }

    return $canonical;
}

add_filter( 'wpseo_canonical', 'yoast_seo_canonical_change_product_category', 99, 1 );
```